# Error de sintaxis bash linux: syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, red-hat

Tengo un archivo de nombre archivo.sh que al correrlo en Red Hat me arroja el siguiente error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `'rchivo.sh: line 7: `for (( i=0; i<=1; i++ ))`
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

mes=(09 10 11 12 01 02)
dias=(30 31 30 31 31 28)
year=(2018 2018 2018 2018 2019 2019)

for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=1; j<=$((${dias[$i]})); j++ ))
    do
    file="${year[$i]}${mes[$i]}$j"
    echo "$file"
    done
done
```

Comment: Copio y pego tu código tal cual como lo pusiste, en mi editor, y al correrlo no me muestra ningún error.

Comment: Por cierto, en tu línea 8, en el segundo for, puedes dejarlo simplemente de la forma `for (( j=1; j<=dias[i]; j++ ))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probé tu script en WSL, que según el `/etc/os-release` es un "Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS" y corrió exitosamente, pero también decidí hacer un contenedor con un, según lo que dice su `/etc/os-release`, "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)", pegué todo y corrió bien, salvo un error que decía algo por el estilo.

> line 14: $'\302': command not found

Y eso me recuerda a cuando algo tiene caracteres no imprimibles. Entonces lo revisé con `cat -An programa`, que muestra los caracteres no imprimibles y a la vez numera cada línea del archivo, y había un metacaracter `M-B` colado, parece ser que es un caracter que se inserta cuando desde windows se copian y pegan cosas desde el clipboard.

Si crees que te pueda estar pasando algo similar, revisa cuidadosamente la salida de

```
cat -An archivo
```

línea por línea, para ver si hay caracteres no imprimibles que te estén perjudicando. También revisa que tus caracteres no alfanuméricos sean los adecuados. Aunque tengo la sospecha de que en esa línea que te marca bash, se pudo haber colado un espacio entre paréntesis o cualquier caracter de más.

Answer (score 1):

Como [ya te dijo Marco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248570/693), no hay ningún problema sintáctico en tu código. Lo más probable es que hayas abierto alguna vez el fichero del script en Windows, [y entonces](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea) tengas lineas que terminan con `\r\n` en vez de `\n`. Para arreglarlo, puedes hacer:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' archivo.sh
```

Comment: O usar `dos2unix`, ¿no?

Comment: @fedorqui claro, pero hay que instalarlo. El sed está en POSIX y siempre estará presente. Además, ya sabes que a mi me mola ;)

Comment: ¡Alguien quiere pensar en `tr -d "\r" archivo`!